# Take nth element of an Iterator

Tags: scala

I have a scala Iterator[A]. How can I reference the nth element of it?

For instance:

```
val myIter: Iterator[Seq[String]] = { .... }

//get the size of the Iterator

val s = myIter.size

//get 3rd element (base 0)

val third:Seq[String] = myIter.get(2)  <---- Something like this?
```

I maybe misreading the docs but can't find a function to do this easily. Thanks for help

Answer (score 8):

If you want to live dangerously,

```
myIter.drop(2).next
```

or if you'd rather be safe

```
myIter.drop(2).take(1).toList.headOption
```

Comment: @sectornitad *How come Iterators are mutable* what makes you say so?

Comment: @om-nom-nom because it says so right here! http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator

Comment: @sectornitad fair enough :-) I mostly think about iterators as **consumables** or **traversable only once** rather than **mutable** structures (although first is a subset of the later).

Comment: Actually something well odd just happened. I had a println(myIter.size) above the code to select the nth element and it DESTROYED the whole Iterator! Just asking the size of the Iterator made the iterator become 'empty'. This is barking mad behaviour!

Comment: @sectornitad that is what [iterators do](http://take.ms/TIw6p) not only in scala, btw. If you need reusage and lazyness consider to look at [Streams](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream). Important note: stream will keep all it's elements in memory.

Comment: @sectornitad - No, it's extremely useful behavior that you just weren't expecting.  In many contexts, requiring that an iterator can be rerun is wasteful or impossible.  `Iterable` is what you want if you want limitless copies of an iterator.

Comment: Ok, makes sense to think of them as consumerables. Use once and then toss. Thanks fellas

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple

```
myIter.slice(n,n+1).toList.headOption
```

Drop.take will get all elements from the beginning. Slice is much more memory efficient

Comment: slice is better, but memory efficiency is same. First thing drop will do is rewind into n-position, same as slice: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L340

Comment: @dk14 Why is slice better?

Comment: @IvanBalashov it's shorter, so it's more idiomatic

Comment: Specifying a range for single element doesn't seem very idiomatic

Comment: @IvanBalashov I didn't say that it's **very** idiomatic...did you read RexKerr's answer? What's **more** idiomatic?